# Setting a title in the top right of a modally presented interface in WatchOS

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, watchos-2, watchos-simulator

Is it possible to do this?  As far as I know the setTitle() method just allows you to change the text of the top left "Cancel" text.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

---

All the `WKInterfaceObject` and `WKInterfaceController` are just proxy objects to send queries to real UI Object. It's huge different with `UIView` and `UIViewController` in iOS.

Storyboard bundle is separated with extension bundle. So, in sand-box concept, you can't access real UI Object directly with extension context. The connection between proxies and real UI Objects are managed by watchOS itself.

As a result, What if there is no query API or interface builder option, There is no way to react or change real UI Objects by code in extension bundle.